# How to Enable/Disable checkbox value inside a dropdown and displaying the multiselected value in the text box using Wpf mvvm

Tags: wpf, mvvm, wpf-controls

Please help me on this issue in WPF using MVVM

I Have a drop down ,In that 5 values were there. Onload the drop down needs to be displayed only enabling the first value and remaining needs to be disable.Once i click/check the first check box under the drop down it needs to be enable all other disabled check boxes values  and also the selected value from the drop-down needs to displayed in the same combo box(multiselect) separated by comma or any delimiters using wpf MVVM architecture.

Comment: Ive built this stuff before. Its a lot of work, and probably beyond the scope of a quick Q&A like here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's something that approximately does what you want. Define a view model for the individual items in the drop down (`ComboBox`):

```
public class ChoiceViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private string _content;
    public string Content
    {
        get => _content;
        set => Set(ref _content, value);
    }

    private bool _isChecked;
    public bool IsChecked
    {
        get => _isChecked;
        set => Set(ref _isChecked, value);
    }

    private bool _isEnabled;
    public bool IsEnabled
    {
        get => _isEnabled;
        set => Set(ref _isEnabled, value);
    }
}
```

The `ViewModelBase` class comes from the [MVVM Light Toolkit](http://www.mvvmlight.net/). It defines the `Set` method I used above, which raises the `INotifyPropertyChanged` event whenever the property is changed.

Next, define a view model to contain the list of choices:

```
public class ViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        Choices = new ObservableCollection<ChoiceViewModel>
        {
            new ChoiceViewModel {Content = "Check to enable the others", IsEnabled = true},
            new ChoiceViewModel {Content = "Choice 1", IsEnabled = false},
            new ChoiceViewModel {Content = "Choice 2", IsEnabled = false},
            new ChoiceViewModel {Content = "Choice 3", IsEnabled = false},
            new ChoiceViewModel {Content = "Choice 4", IsEnabled = false},
        };

        Choices[0].PropertyChanged += (sender, args) =>
        {
            if (args.PropertyName == nameof(ChoiceViewModel.IsChecked))
            {
                var choice = (ChoiceViewModel)sender;
                for (var i = 1; i < Choices.Count; i++)
                    Choices[i].IsEnabled = choice.IsChecked;
                RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(ChoicesDisplay));
            }
        };

        for (var i = 1; i < Choices.Count; i++)
        {
            Choices[i].PropertyChanged += (sender, args) =>
            {
                if (args.PropertyName == nameof(ChoiceViewModel.IsChecked))
                    RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(ChoicesDisplay));
            };
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<ChoiceViewModel> Choices { get; }

    public string ChoicesDisplay =>
        CheckedChoices.Any()
            ? string.Join(", ", CheckedChoices.Select(x => x.Content))
            : "No choices made";

    private IEnumerable<ChoiceViewModel> CheckedChoices =>
        Choices.Skip(1).Where(x => x.IsChecked);
}
```

The view model handles enabling or disabling the other choices when the first choice is checked or unchecked. It also handles updating the display for the choices selected, separated by commas.

In the `Window` class (or whatever is appropriate for your situation), set the `DataContext` to the `ViewModel`:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new ViewModel();
    }
}
```

The XAML looks like this:

```
<ComboBox
    ItemsSource="{Binding Choices}"
    Text="{Binding ChoicesDisplay, Mode=OneWay}"
    IsEditable="True"
    IsReadOnly="True"
    >
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox
                Content="{Binding Content}"
                IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}"
                IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled}"
                />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

This solution does what you want, but there are some things you may want to fix. For example, even though a check box is disabled (and therefore you can't check or uncheck it), you can still choose it in the drop down.

Comment: thank you for the code and its worked as per you mentioned.

Comment: I have a one more doubt...please help me on this if you know 
If a value selected in checkbox (even multiselect) how to display it in the textbox seperated by comma or any delimiter ..... thanks in advance

Comment: @Nirmal Yes, that's possible. Please update your question with the additional requirement, and I'll edit my answer.

Comment: I have updated the question as per my requirement.....can you please help me on this by editing the solution that you provided

Comment: @Nirmal OK, I've updated my answer. If you're satisfied please mark it as the answer.

Comment: Hi @devcurry ,Thanks for your solution and it working as per my requirement and I marked this as a solution.